# Linked servers select taking way to long

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Moving some complicated reporting sprocs to a centralized server and time went from 5 seconds to 30+ seconds.

validating what take so long via:

```
print '04 NWA Raw data Numeric'
print datediff(ss, @now, getdate())
set @now = GETDATE()
```

I am attempting to only pull local what this report needs with these queries:

> 1355 rows in 10 seconds----

```
select * 
into #nwaDump
from [Phoenix].[NWA].dbo.QISDataNumeric
where rowguid in (
select rowguid from [Phoenix].[NWA].[dbo].[QISDataText] nd
where nd.DataValue in ( '41310291            ' ) 
)
```

> 249 rows in 28 seconds

```
select * 
into #nwaText 
from [Phoenix].[NWA].[dbo].[QISDataText] td
where td.DataValue in ( '41310291            ' )
```

Same two queries run on other server < 1 second return time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `OPENQUERY` for this, since it should make the filters on the linked server and then pull them to your other server:

```
SELECT *
INTO #nwaText 
FROM OPENQUERY(Phoenix,'SELECT * FROM [NWA].[dbo].[QISDataText] 
                        WHERE DataValue in ( ''41310291            '' )')
```

Comment: Found that I didn't need the OpenQuery when I placed the real values into the in clause.  It was the Into # that was killing me.